# PostgreSQL Installing issue

Tags: database, postgresql

I downloaded PostgreSQL.

In the last step during installation i got this error [Failed to load modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydr3k.png) then i got this [running post-install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ctGI.png)

Can anyone help please

Comment: Do you see any error messages in file described [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/11.0/PG_Inst_Guide_v11/PostgreSQL_Installation_Guide.1.13.html#)?

Comment: No, i tried also to install as an administrator and i get the same result

Comment: Can you share the environment you use?

Comment: i solve the problem by installing postgresql with graphical installer by BigSQL, the problem seems with EntrepriseDB( it works fine when i installed the first time but when i uninstalled it and reinstalled again i got this problem of sql modules).